# Extending JFrame Creates New JFrame Object

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, extends, japplet

I've been creating a fairly complex applet using JFrames extending other JFrames on NetBeans and I'm having issues with accessing data from previous JFrame screens. Looking at the diagram below:

1. My applet opens with a main screen (`MainScreen`) with a button for accessing a new page for editing .xls pages (`EditScore`). This page extends a kind of skeleton JFrame (`MenuSkeleton`) which is a general form for `EditScore` and other pages (call them `Edit1` and `Edit2`) which can be accessed through `MainScreen`. I use `MenuSkeleton` because both of these pages are only slightly different from each other.
2. `MenuSkeleton` opens a file chooser in `EditScore` which allows users to choose a .xls page to edit and saves this page's name in the integer `xlsName` (saved in `MenuSkeleton`). So `xlsName` is initialized as an empty String in `MenuSkeleton` but given a new value in `EditScore`.
3. `EditScore` has a button which opens the .xls editor (`EditingWindow`). `EditingWindow` extends `WindowSkeleton` which extends `MenuSkeleton` because:

   -I need to access `xlsName` in `WindowSkeleton`

   -`WindowSkeleton` can't extend `EditScore` because sometimes it is called through `Edit1` and `Edit2` and doesn't even open `EditScore`.

**My problem is with accessing `xlsName.`** I can access `xlsName` just fine in MenuSkeleton and in EditScore, but once I try to access it in `WindowSkeleton` or `EditingWindow`,  it's null. I'm guessing this means a new instance of `MenuSkeleton` is being created when I extend it in `WindowSkeleton`. Is there a way for me to access the value `xlsName` is given in `editFolder`?

Thanks for reading through this ridiculous question! I'm sorry it's so long and confusing - I'll add/modify based on any suggestions I receive.

[image]

Comment: A "applet" refers to a "component which is embedded into a web page" - Just to be clear, the Applet API is effectively deprecated and is no longer supported. *"using JFrames extending other JFrames"* - This is a good example of a bad design.  You should avoid extending from top level containers, lots of reasons, but primarily, they are inflexible and difficult to re-use or extend later

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions for what I could be doing instead?

Comment: *"'m guessing this means a new instance of MenuSkeleton is being created when I extend it in WindowSkeleton*" - That's not "entirely" accurate, but I appreciate why you think this - A new "instance" of `MenuSkeleton` isn't be created when you "extend" `WindowSkeleton`.  But, when you create an instance of `WindowSkeleton` the properties inherited from `MenuSkeleton` are been initialised to their default values - the wording is just off

Comment: *"Is there a way for me to access the value xlsName is given in editFolder?"* - This a basic and very common practice. You should start by taking a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: So why are they initialized again for WindowSkeleton and not MenuSkeleton?

Comment: They are, when you create either and instance of `EditScore` or `EditingWindow`, all the properties defined by the class and those inherited are initialised to their default values, but `EditScore` is providing you with a means to open a file as part of it's work flow

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177137/discussion-between-molly-taylor-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand `EditingWindow` and `EditScore` both extend `MenuSkeleton`. But `EditingWindow` also extends `WindowSkeleton`. Try bypassing `WindowSkeleton` and extend `EditingWindow` directly from `MenuSkeleton`. Extending from two classes one of which is already a subclass causes problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: For the worst case, just keep the Excel filename in a global variable.